How to Compile OpenCV with CUDA Support on Ubuntu 20.04 for YOLO GPU Acceleration in Python?
I'm relatively new to OpenCV and I'm looking for some guidance on how to compile the latest version of OpenCV with CUDA support on Ubuntu 20.04. I intend to run YOLO with Python on my PC using the GPU instead of the CPU.
The problem: After a lot of research I've been unable to find clear, straightforward instructions for compiling OpenCV with CUDA on Ubuntu 20.04, and then configure my environment to use this version of OpenCV in Python.
While I'm aware that the Python library can be installed directly, it unfortunately isn't built with the CUDA modules that I need.
My environment:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Mar_28_02:18:24_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.4, V12.4.131
Build cuda_12.4.r12.4/compiler.34097967_0

**nvidia-smi**
Tue Apr 30 18:25:09 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.15              Driver Version: 550.54.15      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P3             N/A /   35W |      12MiB /   4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2118      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3195      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I found in the official OpenCV documentation "Installation in Linux" which covers installation on Ubuntu 18.04 and doesn't mention anything about the flags needed for compiling with CUDA support or how to use the compiled version in Python later on.
The documentation on the official repo leads to the openCV official documentation.
I also found this tutorial but it's 4 years old and it's for ubuntu 18.04
The question is how to compile OpenCV with CUDA on Ubuntu 20.04 to use it in Python or where to find detailed official documentation?

You tagged "yolo" but didn't say which framework you are using.  I'm going to give you an answer about Darknet/YOLO, the original "YOLO" framework.
The good news is, you don't need to build OpenCV with CUDA support.  Darknet uses CUDA directly, not through OpenCV.  In the YOLO FAQ, see this question:
https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#opencv_and_cuda

You definitely should NOT build OpenCV by hand! [...]
Please take note: Darknet DOES NOT use the CUDA portion of OpenCV! Don't bother spending hours (days?) trying to install it, Darknet wont use it. At all!


Darknet does use CUDA to train and run the neural network, but it does so directly, not via OpenCV. OpenCV is used to load images from disk, resize images, and data augmentation such as the "mosaic" images, all of which is done without the GPU.

You also mention Python.  The good news is Darknet/YOLO has Python bindings.  So if you follow the normal Linux installation steps (see here) then you should have easy access to YOLO from within your Python app.
The Darknet/YOLO repo has a "src-python" directory with some example code.  To get started, see example.py.
If you're looking for some advanced features, you may also want to look at DarkHelp, the alternative CLI/library to access Darknet/YOLO.  It also has Python bindings for some (not all) of the advanced features.
If you really want to re-build OpenCV, then I strongly suggest you stop trying to use blog posts, and use the vcpkg tool.  This will build the OpenCV library correctly for you every time.  You'd run something like vcpkg install opencv[cuda,python,contrib,core,dnn,ffmpeg,jpeg,png,quirc,tiff,webp]  Obviously look up and include the modules you need.
Disclaimer:  I maintain the Darknet/YOLO codebase, and I'm the author of DarkHelp, DarkMark, and many other YOLO-related tools.

Thanks but the whole idea is to use OpenCV with python since it's open source, and to enable CUDA to use the GPU. This are the requirements. Right now, using another framework or use the CPU is not an option


That information was not available in your question, 2) Yes, Darknet/YOLO uses OpenCV and everything is open-source.  Darknet/YOLO does use the GPU+CUDA+cuDNN, not sure why you say "use the CPU is not an option".  Note my answer did also include the vcpkg command to install OpenCV+CUDA.


When using OpenCV with python, you can use the CPU or GPU for training and then running the model. For performance I need my code to use the GPU, and that's why it's not an option to just use the precompiled OpenCV library that can be installed with pip. Darknet might work for what I need, but still it's now what I'm looking for. Last, if you can provide some official documentation of how to achieve what I'm asking with vcpkg it would be grate, can't find anything straight forward for compiling in my environment and then get the library that I can use with python.

You still didn't read what I wrote.  I did not suggest you install it with pip.  What I suggested is you install it with vcpkg, which will install the CUDA version of OpenCV.  And note that OpenCV's DNN module cannot train.  You can only use it for inference.  To train, you'll need something different.  My answer included the command you need to run to install OpenCV+CUDA via vcpkg.

vcpkg is for c/c++ packages, my ultimate goal is to compile OpenCV and have a python library that I can use in Python

Which is why in the command I told you to run, I included the "python" option.  Please re-read my answer.

any chance you can share the source of this, hopefully official documentation where it's specified the "python" option?
